# How to disable Emacs-Flymake for html mode

Tags: emacs, flymake

Here is my flymake setup in .emacs file:

```
 (when (load "flymake" t) 
         (defun flymake-pyflakes-init () 
           (let* ((temp-file (flymake-init-create-temp-buffer-copy 
                              'flymake-create-temp-inplace)) 
              (local-file (file-relative-name 
                           temp-file 
                           (file-name-directory buffer-file-name)))) 
             (list "pyflakes" (list local-file)))) 

         (add-to-list 'flymake-allowed-file-name-masks 
                  '("\\.py\\'" flymake-pyflakes-init))) 

   (add-hook 'find-file-hook 'flymake-find-file-hook)
(load-library "flymake-cursor")
```

I want to use flymake only for .py files. and disable it for the rest. but It is always enabled. 
For example when I open an html file I always get following error
Error (flymake): Flymake: Failed to launch syntax check process 'xml' with args (val /home/huseyin/vipsatis/templates/cancellation/base_flymake.html): Searching for program: no such file or directory, xml. Flymake will be switched OFF

So I want to turn it off for anything but py files. is it possible?

(
For the people having the same problem, I want to explain the error message: Flymake uses xmlstarlet for xml and html validation. And it tries to call it as "xml val ......" but it has to call it as "xmlstarlet val...." to fix this you have to find flymake.el file and change the xml call with xmlstarlet.
)

Comment: I've followed all the suggestions below to no avail. Flymake mode is still active in my html buffers, which is really annoying when I'm using django tags. Any tips? I'm on Snow Leopard running emacs24.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Remove the HTML entry from the list:

```
(delete '("\\.html?\\'" flymake-xml-init) flymake-allowed-file-name-masks)
```

Comment: When I try this, I get the error `Symbol's value as variable is void: flymake-allowed-file-name-masks`

Comment: Although I don't know exactly why, putting the line at the end of `.emacs` won't have the error.

Comment: @RNA It's probably because `flymake-allowed-file-name-masks` doesn't exist until loading the flymake package creates it. By putting the delete command at the end of your `.emacs` file, you're giving the package time to create the list.

Answer (score 6):

OK I got it. here is what I did:
first of all I found flymake.el file.(If you dont have it you probably have flymake.elc file under emacs installation.In that case just copy flymake.el file under your load path so it will be used instead of compiled version(.elc file) under insallation).
than I found following function and commented .xml and .html bindings.

```
(defcustom flymake-allowed-file-name-masks
  '(("\\.\\(?:c\\(?:pp\\|xx\\|\\+\\+\\)?\\|CC\\)\\'" flymake-simple-make-init)
    ;("\\.xml\\'" flymake-xml-init)
    ;("\\.html?\\'" flymake-xml-init)
    ("\\.cs\\'" flymake-simple-make-init)
    ("\\.p[ml]\\'" flymake-perl-init)
    ("\\.php[345]?\\'" flymake-php-init)
    ("\\.h\\'" flymake-master-make-header-init flymake-master-cleanup)
    ("\\.java\\'" flymake-simple-make-java-init flymake-simple-java-cleanup)
    ("[0-9]+\\.tex\\'" flymake-master-tex-init flymake-master-cleanup)
    ("\\.tex\\'" flymake-simple-tex-init)
    ("\\.idl\\'" flymake-simple-make-init)
    ;; ("\\.cpp\\'" 1)
    ;; ("\\.java\\'" 3)
    ;; ("\\.h\\'" 2 ("\\.cpp\\'" "\\.c\\'")
    ;; ("[ \t]*#[ \t]*include[ \t]*\"\\([\w0-9/\\_\.]*[/\\]*\\)\\(%s\\)\"" 1 2))
    ;; ("\\.idl\\'" 1)
    ;; ("\\.odl\\'" 1)
    ;; ("[0-9]+\\.tex\\'" 2 ("\\.tex\\'")
    ;; ("[ \t]*\\input[ \t]*{\\(.*\\)\\(%s\\)}" 1 2 ))
    ;; ("\\.tex\\'" 1)
    )
```

Other comment outed lines was already there. Now flymake does not work for html and xml files

Comment: you don't have to modify the .el file to make this happen.  you can just set the variable in your own emacs.el (or equivalent).

Comment: so if I understand right, I have to put the code in the post in emacs.el file. so it will overwrite tthe one in flymake.el file. I will try that thank you. (If I am mistaking please correct me)

Answer (score 3):

In the error message you receive it's telling that it can't find the command-line XML validation tool `xml`. You can fix it by installing a compatible XML validation tool (`xmllint` is the right choice I guess).

But if you really just want to disable Flymake for HTML and XML files you don't have to copy whole the flymake.el file and change it. Simply add this line your init file:

```
(defun flymake-xml-init ())
```

This overrides the function that Flymake calls for HTML and XML files with an empty function.

Comment: +1 Not sure why you were downvoted, this seems normal for disabling other modes [like java](https://github.com/mostafah/conf/commit/1e4c545d3d83372a25c8649cc222a529f7e4a78e), even though it didn't work for me.

Comment: I used `(defun flymake-simple-make-init ())` to disable all the make-based flymake modes at once.  Very handy.

Answer (score 3):

Customize the variable named `flymake-allowed-file-name-masks`.

You can do it like this too:

```
M-x customize-variable RET

flymake-allowed-file-name-masks RET
```